# Java NIO Prevent multiple socket connections from the same PC

Tags: java, actionscript-3, flash, sockets, netty

I am working on a Client - Server game on Facebook, and I need to prevent players from using two facebook account on the same computer from playing (cheating), The server side is Netty IO and the client is flash. 
I thought about checking the client IPs but a lot of the players are behind NAT and many times multiple clients have the same ip.

Comment: Why is that cheating?

Comment: I don't think Flash app hosted on html page can read client machine MAC address. It may be possible in Flex application with full privileges and a native helper library. Sure users may spoof MAC but doing it per concurrent application processes would require even more tricks. So in the end if you are able to read MAC it gives a decent level of (concurrent)multi-account guard within a single PC.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for something to identify a client then consider using the MAC address of one of the network cards in the client's computer.

Comment: Yes MAC addresses can be changed but in the scenarion mentioned above it does not make sense. As user is trying to prevent to logins from the same machine. If a user changes it, the network adapter will be reset and the current connection will be lost. So it is safe to use the MAC address for the above stated problem.